# ERROR displaying image in php

Tags: php, image

Im my project only image name are stored to `SQL` So that i can display it using name and image file is stored in folder

My problem is unable to display image since i have to specify path

```
<?php
// Connection data (server_address, database, name, poassword)
$hostdb = 'localhost';
$namedb = '3ss';
$userdb = 'sanoj';
$passdb = '123456';

try {
  // Connect and create the PDO object
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostdb; dbname=$namedb", $userdb, $passdb);
  $conn->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");      // Sets encoding UTF-8

  // Define and perform the SQL SELECT query
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM `mobile` where id=50";
  $result = $conn->query($sql);

  // Parse returned data, and displays them
  while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
      echo  $row['id']. '/'. $row['mcat']. '/'. $row['image1']. '/'.'<li><img src=\poster\process\mobile\thumb\"',$row['image1'],'"></li>' .'/'. $row['image3']. '<br />';
  }

  $conn = null;        // Disconnect
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: first thing to check if the image is not showing is to actually check if you have set the right path. (backslashes) you sure?

Comment: Your code is wrapping the filename in an extra pair of double quotes - you can see this on your screen shot.Remove those extra quotes.

Comment: 'not according to the `src` value. you have a superfluous `"`

Comment: @HoboSapiens i was trying to remove but when i try i get error in code

Comment: that path is probably wrong - you're dealing with http, and should be using `/` instead, plus `"9e.....jpg""`? That's very wrong.

Comment: @Ghost check my question when i remove `"` i get error in code

Comment: @HoboSapiens check my question when i remove `"` i get error in code

Comment: man i don't know if this is a trick question. anyways, wrap source value with quotes, not the filename, the whole bit. `'<li><img src="/poster/process/mobile/thumb/'.$row['image1'].'" /></li>'`

Comment: @Ghost thanks your comment works

Comment: From the newly posted screen shot it looks like there may be an unmatched double-quote somewhere up the code that's causing the IDE to complain. Editing out a couple of double quotes shouldn't be difficult so I'm not sure we're getting the whole story. I think I'll move on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use php variables inside the html tag. This should work:

```
.'<li><img src=\poster\process\mobile\thumb\$row["image1"]></li>'
```

It is important that you are consistent with when to use double quotes and when not to. the $row should have different quotes than the ones surrounding the html tag.

Comment: no, single quoted strings do not interpolate variables inside it.